# Как прописать путь к файлу в пакете, который работает из других пакетов в Go?

Tags: golang

Если в go мы создаем пакет, в котором, например возвращается контент одного из файлов из папки пакета.
Пример пакета, который работает с файлом:

```
package pac
import (
    "io/ioutil"
)
func Get() []byte {
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile( "./files/file.txt")
    return content
}
```

То при попытке выполнить функцию Get из другого пакета
Пример "другого" пакета:

```
package main
import (
    "путь/к/пакету1/pac"
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    fmt.Println(string(pac.Get()))
}
```

Мы получаем ошибку, что такого файла не существует.
Структура файлов:

```
 main/
 -main.go
 -pac/
 --pac.go
 --files/
 ---file.txt
```

Дело в том, что при обращении к пакету pac из main путь к файлу `"./files/file.txt"` уже не подходит, а подходить будет `"./pac/files/file.txt"`
Но как это обойти?
Как сделать так, что бы при обращении из любого места к pac.Get() мы получали контент файла?
Можно, написать длинный абсолютный путь, но ведь он везде разный, на локальном компе один, а на продакшне другой.
В Go я новичок и мне кажется, что что-то упускаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata

эту программу надо скомпилировать и положить в PATH.

затем внутрь исходников вставьте комментарий вида:
//go:generate go-bindata -pkg pac files/

Теперь при выполнении go generate файлы из папки files будут конвертированы в файл bindata.go и при компилировании будут встроены в бинарник - т.е. к ним всегда будет доступ при выполнении.

Answer (score 1):

Мой основной ответ - *не делайте так.* Это же хардкод и волшебные строки. Как вы собираетесь это тестировать? Что если конечный пользователь обязан положить файл куда-то ещё? Что если появится требование читать из stdin? Ну и самое главное как вы собираетесь подобную программу распространять? Вместе со всем исходным кодом? И чтобы запускали всегда из одного места?

На вашем месте, я бы сделал

```
func Method(filename string) (foo, error) { /* ... */ }
```

а ещё лучше - скрыть "файловость" и сделать

```
func Method(r io.Reader) (foo, error) { /* ... */ }
```

---

Если же вы хотите *сохранить содержание файла в самом бинарнике,* воспользуйтесь кодогенераторами типа go-bindata.

Comment: Давайте я расскажу для чего мне это... У меня есть пакет, есть тесты, все заготовки ответов для тестов лежат в файлах в папке mock_responses. И все работало хорошо, пока я не решил протестировать новый функции из пакета  main. Эти функции запускают как раз что-то вроде pac.Get() и путь к файлу mock-ответа теперь неверный

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко Во-первых, очень странно, что у вас один модуль вызывает тестовые методы другого модуля. Во-вторых, если вы всё же хотите сохранить подобную конфигурацию, вы можете определить путь как (прости господи) глобальную переменную модуля, либо устанавливать через переменные окружения.